# Possible to have ScrollingViewBehavior combined with Snackbar behavior?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout`, `Toolbar`, `DrawerLayout`, and `FrameLayout` as my base `Activity` layout but I am having trouble with some overlapping with the `Toolbar`. I insert different `Fragments` into the `FrameLayout`.

**Activity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarOverlay"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarOverlay"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="10dp"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.walintukai.lovelupdating.widgets.SnackbarBehavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#80858585"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="#bf333333"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I run this, my `Toolbar` is overlapping the content of the `FrameLayout` and is on top of it, when I want it to be underneath it like a LinearLayout.

**How do I adjust it so the contents of the `FrameLayout` sits below the `Toolbar` and not being overlapped by it?**

Update 1: 
I have tested using `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` as the behavior for the `FrameLayout` and it gives me the intended behavior for the `Toolbar`, but then it removes the `Snackbar` push behavior. How can I combine two behaviors together?

I have tried extending `ScrollingViewBehavior` and combining the two behaviors, but when the Snackbar is showing it pushes the layout up under the Toolbar still. If I dismiss the Snackbar, everything looks fine.